# How to prevent a pthread to be suspended in background mode on iOS

Tags: ios, background, pthreads

I have an app that functions perfectly well, with some background pthreads doing some networking stuff. However when the app goes in background mode, the threads are suspended. Is there anyway to prevent that or do I have to put them in the background task stuff?

Thanks